# How to get selected item index from treeview WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I am quite new with WPF and your help or advice would be appreciated.

Is there any way to get selected item index from treeview? For example, I select the following:

[Select item in treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fQYS.png) - from which I am trying to get index [Group,Subgroup] or [1,2] (in picture)

XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeViewVariable" Margin="10,71,522,10">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:GroupBuilder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" - " Foreground="Blue" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Members.Count}" Foreground="Blue" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:GroupMember}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" [ " Foreground="Red" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Foreground="Red" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" ]" Foreground="Red" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

How I format the list:

```
    public class GroupBuilder
    {
        public GroupBuilder()
        {
            this.Members = new ObservableCollection<GroupMember>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<GroupMember> Members { get; set; }
    }

    public class GroupMember
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Generate groups and bind ItemsSource:

```
    List <GroupBuilder> groups = new List<GroupBuilder>();

    GroupBuilder group1 = new GroupBuilder() { Name = "Group 1" };
    group1.Members.Add(new GroupMember() { Name = "Variable 1", Value = 23 });
    group1.Members.Add(new GroupMember() { Name = "Variable 2", Value = 34 });
    group1.Members.Add(new GroupMember() { Name = "Variable 3", Value = 45 });
    groups.Add(group1);

    GroupBuilder group2 = new GroupBuilder() { Name = "Group 2" };
    group2.Members.Add(new GroupMember() { Name = "Variable 1", Value = 45 });
    group2.Members.Add(new GroupMember() { Name = "Variable 2", Value = 56 });
    group2.Members.Add(new GroupMember() { Name = "Variable 3", Value = 21 });
    group2.Members.Add(new GroupMember() { Name = "Variable 4", Value = 32 });
    groups.Add(group2);

    GroupBuilder group3 = new GroupBuilder() { Name = "Group 3" };
    group3.Members.Add(new GroupMember() { Name = "Variable 1", Value = 332 });
    groups.Add(group3);

    treeViewVariable.ItemsSource = groups;
```

Comment: TreeView is designed to display any Graphs, and not just tree-like ones.
In an arbitrary graph, there is no such thing as a "vertex index".
Therefore TreeView doesn't define it either.
You can get the selected vertex in the SelecteItem property.
And then try to find its index in the source collection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @EldHasp, I will definitely try to look into this.